# Apply proper finishes on obj model in scenekit?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I am trying to apply metalness map on .obj Model using scenekit (ARIkit iOS). Unfortunately, It's displaying vertical lines.

Please refer below code and also, I have attached screenshot for proper understanding.

Model is UV unwrapped to resolve tiling issue in the model, and all materials are attached for review purpose.

**Obj URL** : https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/p9-platform/product/4f800e4c-52cd-4167-a7c3-6ba5703df7e7.obj

```
func loadTexture(forMaterial material: SCNMaterial, withFinish finish:FinishModel, forDispatchGroup disPatchGroup:DispatchGroup) {

    concurrentQueue.async {
        if material.lightingModel != .physicallyBased {
            material.lightingModel = .physicallyBased
        }
    }
    if let finishMap = finish.finishMap {
      if let diffuseTexturePath = finishMap.diffuseMapUrl {
            disPatchGroup.enter()
            self.dataProvider.fetchTextureFile(forpath: diffuseTexturePath, successBlock: { (success, imageObject) in
                //self.viewController?.report_memory()
                material.diffuse.contents = nil
                material.diffuse.contents = imageObject
                disPatchGroup.leave()
            }, failureBlock: { (error) in
                disPatchGroup.leave()
            })
        }

       if let metalTexturePath = finishMap.metalnessMapUrl {
            disPatchGroup.enter()
            self.dataProvider.fetchTextureFile(forpath: metalTexturePath, successBlock: { (success, imageObject) in
               // self.viewController?.report_memory()
               material.metalness.contents = nil
                material.metalness.contents = imageObject
                disPatchGroup.leave()
            }, failureBlock: { (error) in
                disPatchGroup.leave()
            })
        }

        if let roughnessTexturePath = finishMap.roughnessMapUrl {
            disPatchGroup.enter()
            self.dataProvider.fetchTextureFile(forpath: roughnessTexturePath, successBlock: { (success, imageObject) in
               // self.viewController?.report_memory()
                material.roughness.contents = nil
                material.roughness.contents = imageObject
                disPatchGroup.leave()
            }, failureBlock: { (error) in
                disPatchGroup.leave()
            })
        }

        if let normalTexturePath = finishMap.normalMapUrl {
            disPatchGroup.enter()
            self.dataProvider.fetchTextureFile(forpath: normalTexturePath, successBlock: { (success, imageObject) in
                material.normal.contents = nil
               // self.viewController?.report_memory()
                material.normal.contents = imageObject
                disPatchGroup.leave()
            }, failureBlock: { (error) in
                disPatchGroup.leave()
            })
        }

    }
}
```

[image][image]

DiffuseMapUrl
[image]

NormalMapUrl
[image]

metalnessMapUrl
[image]

roughnessMapUrl
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure the different material properties (`diffuse`, `metalness`, `roughness` and `normal`) use the same [wrap mode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnwrapmode) for [`wrapS`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterialproperty/1395384-wraps) and [`wrapT`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterialproperty/1395382-wrapt). Here [`SCNWrapModeRepeat`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnwrapmode/scnwrapmoderepeat) is likely what you are looking for.

**Note** The code in the question sets the `specular` material property, but [`SCNLightingModelPhysicallyBased`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnlightingmodelphysicallybased) does not take it into account.